# Convert only parts of a filename to uppercase

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression, filenames, expr

In a shell script program, I need to convert the filenames to uppercase if the converted filename does not already exist. In this particular case I need to change only the basename to uppercase leaving the extension (if any) as it is.

My idea of doing the problem is to extract first the basename and the extension separately, convert the basename to uppercase using 
`tr` command and then check whether the changed basename along with the extension exists in the directory or not.

If it does not exist then I will change the original filename with the uppercase basename using mv. Now I think that this can be done in two ways: firstly using `expr` and secondly using `cut` with `.` (space-period-space) as the delimiter.

If I want to use `expr` for extracting the basename (for eg. from the filename - `python1.py` or `phonelist`) then I have written this:

```bsh
basefile=`expr "$filename" : '\(.*\)\.*.*' `
```

I have used `\.*` for those filenames also which do not have any extension because `\.*`  would ignore zero or more occurrences of `.`, but this expression for `expr` is not working properly. For any filename, it is returning the whole filename as it is.

Can anyone please explain where am I wrong. Also please suggest how can I use `expr` to extract only the extension from the filename.

Comment: Have you tried using the `basename` command to extract it?

Comment: As a side note, do not use the old-style backtick notation for command-substitutions, it is deprecated and should be replaced by the `$( ... )` notation, i.e. `basefile="$(expr "$filename" : '\(.*\)\.*.*')"` in your case.

Comment: @Dagelf Yes but for using `basename` we must know the extension already. But in this case the files may have any extension

Comment: @roaima Bash shell

Comment: @Admin Ok thankyou. Actually in the book I follow it is given within backtick notation. That's why I have used it.

Answer (score 7):

If the shell is `bash`, using just bash parameters expansion:

```
file="aaa.bbb.dat"

name=${file%.*} # delete everything after last dot 
ext=${file##*.} # delete everything up to last dot
upcase=${name^^*}.$ext # uppercase everything

echo "$upcase"
```

```
AAA.BBB.dat
```

Trying with a more difficult case:

```
file="déjà vu . dat "
name=${file%.*} # delete everything after last dot 
ext=${file##*.} # delete everything up to last dot
upcase=${name^^*}.$ext # uppercase everything
echo ":$upcase:"
```

Gives:

```
:DÉJÀ VU . dat :
```

So:

- double quotes aren't necessary, until using the result
- Uppercase seems OK even for non-ASCII characters

Comment: Just one question: @Gilles already proposed that in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580188/377345) but cautioned that non-ASCII characters may not be correctly transformed; can you comment on whether the `bash` internals do that correctly?

Comment: @roaima Doesn't seem necessary, counter-example gladly accepted

Comment: @AdminBee Seems to work OK, see edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

When there's an ambiguity in how far a group extends, regex engines favor the longest match first. For any file name, `\(.*\)` matches the whole name and `\.*.*` matches the empty string.

You'll need two cases: with or without extension. Note also that if a file name starts with a `.`, that's not the start of an extension.

I don't understand why you want to use `expr`. Shell parameter manipulation is easier.

On converting to uppercase, note that the `tr` implementation on Linux does not support non-ASCII locales. It only does byte manipulation. For example `echo accentué | tr a-z A-Z` results in `ACCENTUé`, not `ACCENTUÉ`. Use a locale-aware tool such as awk instead. In bash, you can use `${filename^^?}`, but that's not available in sh. Make sure that your script is running in the correct locale for the file names' encoding.

I assume that the filename doesn't contain a directory part. If it does, separate it first.

```
case $filename in
  ?*.*) # There is an extension
    base="${filename%.*}"; ext=".${filename##*.}";;
  *) # No extension
    base="$filename"; ext="";;
esac
upcased_base="$(printf %s. %base | awk '$0 = toupper($0)')"
upcased="${upcased_base%.}$ext"
```

The trailing `.` in `%s.` that then gets stripped from `$upcased_base` ensures that the script correctly handles file names with a newline immediately before the extension. Without this, the command substitution would strip off trailing newlines. You don't need this if you've already ensured that your file names don't contain newline characters.

Comment: Why does \.*.* matches empty string? Can you please explain

Comment: This is because `*` means "zero or more" of the preceding character/sub-expression in the context of regular expressions.

Comment: Actually I am just a beginner in learning shell scripting and linux commands. Till now I know very few commands and one of those is `expr` . That's why I tried to do this problem using `expr` .

Comment: Can you please explain what does # and % mean in your code.

Comment: If you are new to bash scripting, I would recommend the [Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for a good overview. In addition, using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) - also available as standalone tool in many Linux distributions - can help debug shell scripts and prevent unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Admin Yes that I know  but I cannot understand why does this expression matches empty string. As far as I guess, `\.*` will match zero or more occurences of . which is required for the extension to be ignored if it exists.Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Priyanka Zero occurrences of anything is the empty string. Regarding `${…#…}` and `${…%…}`, they are constructs to take the value of a variable and remove a prefix or suffix. See for example the bash manual under “[Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)”. These constructs are available in all sh variants. `expr` is mostly an obsolete tool that is no longer useful with shells from the 1990s and later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an entirely `awk`-based solution, where you would put the following line in your shell script:

```bsh
uppercasename="$(echo "$filename" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NF==1{$1=toupper($1)} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) $i=toupper($i)} 1')"
```

This will use the `.` as field separator *for input and output* and, if only one field is found, convert that to uppercase, and in all other cases convert all but the last fields to uppercase. It then prints the result (this is the meaning of the `1`, which is a shorthand notation for `{print}`).

If you are using `bash`, you could get rid of the pipe and state it as

```bsh
uppercasename="$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NF==1{$1=toupper($1)} {for (i=1;i<NF;i++) $i=toupper($i)} 1' <<< "$filename")"
```

using a here-string.

Note that this is designed so that in the borderline case of a filename ending in a `.`, as in `myfile.this.txt.`, it will treat that like an "empty but present suffix" and convert it to `MYFILE.THIS.TXT.`. Also, if the filename *starts* with a `.` and has no other extension (as in `.myfile`), it will keep that as lowercase.